# How to resolve custom type while passing object as argument

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to call `Create` method from any program to match what class type is passed on based on while perform operation.

So the problem is how do I resolve an anonymous type while passing to a private methods?

I am calling from :

```
_productService.Create<Supplier>(_supplier);
```

To my class method :

```
public class ProductService
{
    public void Create<T>(T obj)
    {
        switch (obj.GetType().Name)
        {
            case "Supplier":
                Supplier(); //Call Supplier Method;
                break;
            case "Product":
                Product(); //Call Supplier Method;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void Supplier<T>(T s)
    {
        //statements
    }

    private void Product()
    {
        //statements
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using a switch case with hard coded strings to match the type of the object, then the whole idea of Generics is meaningless here. This can be refactored easily with some of the well known design patterns. Please don't ask me what are those design patterns :-) take a look at dofactory.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about changing your class to something like:

```
public class ProductService
{
    public void Create<T>(T obj)
    {
        if (typeof(Supplier) == typeof(T))
            Supplier(obj); //Call Supplier Method;
        else if (typeof(Product) == typeof(Product))
            Product(); //Call Product Method;
        else
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Unrecognized type", "type");
    }

    private void Supplier<T>(T s)
    {
        //statements
        Console.WriteLine("Supplier");
    }
    private void Product()
    {
        //statements
        Console.WriteLine("Product");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a less than ideal use case for generics.  Have you considered using simple method overloads instead.  Try the following:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        var service = new ProductService();
        service.Create(new Product());
        service.Create(new Supplier());
        service.Create(new {name="test"});
    }
}


public class ProductService
{
    public void Create(Product obj)
    {
        Product();
    }
    public void Create(Supplier obj)
    {
        Supplier();
    }
    public void Create(Object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unknown type called" + obj.GetType().Name);
    }

    private void Supplier()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Supplier called");
    }
    private void Product()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Product called");
    }
}
public class Product {}
public class Supplier {}
```

Here is a dotnetfiddle for the above: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lzaAba